# Reference to which String object is returned from the pool when calling intern()

Tags: java, string, string-pool

The Java Language Specification states that

> When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a
>   string equal to this String object as determined by the
>   equals(java.lang.Object) method, then the string from the pool is
>   returned

In the following code snippet:

```
class StringPoolTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) { 

    String first = "string";
    String second = new String("string");
    String third = "string".intern();

    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(first));
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(second));
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(third));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
989184670
268130470
989184670
```

I added a String object *first* to the pool (assigning a String literal to the reference) and explicitly created *second* using a String constructor.
There are now **two** identical character sequences in the pool.

I wanted to see which one would be returned when calling *intern*. Since the method *hashCode* is overridden for the class String, I used *System.identityHashCode* to see exactly which two String references were the same.

Clearly, *intern* returned the reference to the object created using a String literal. Why is this so? Are there any rules regarding which reference is returned in the case of multiple identical String objects in the pool?

Comment: "There are now two identical character sequences in the pool." No, `new String("string")` creates a new string, equal to `"string"`, which is not in the pool.

Comment: @AndyTurner not all String objects are in the pool?

Comment: If all string objects were in the pool, what would be the need for the `intern()` method?

Comment: @0lt: Correct, not all String objects are in the pool. Only *interned* String objects are in the string pool. All literals are interned when the class containing them is loaded. Others are only interned on request.

Comment: Well, this is a revelation. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*How does String.intern() work and how does it affect the String pool?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932486/how-does-string-interns-work-and-how-does-it-affect-the-string-pool) (And a related duplicate of it from yesterday which may also help as it's quite similar to the above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139521/string-pool-behaves-differently-when-used-with-concat).)

Comment: There are no "multiple identical String objects in the pool". They are all unique.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does String.intern() work and how does it affect the String pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932486/how-does-string-intern-work-and-how-does-it-affect-the-string-pool)

Answer (score 0):

When a string literal(without using new Operator) is created, the JVM checks whether that  String exists in the internal list or not. If it already exists in the list, then it does not create a new String and it uses reference to the existing String Object.

JVM does this type of checking internally for String literal but not for String object, which it creates through 'new' keyword i.e. using new always a new string is returned.